# Run open file with Opendialog and execute it

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I want to do something like this:

```
ShellExecute(0, nil, PChar('E:\generic\mpv\mpv.exe'), PChar(''+TntOpenDialog1.FileName+''), nil, SW_HIDE);
```

but nothing happened.
When I try to do something with code like this:

```
TntLabel1.Caption:=PChar(TntOpenDialog1.FileName);
```

it just shows me the first letter of file which I selected before.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: When asking a question like this it pays to tell us which delphi version you use, and the fact that you use Tnt Unicode components. We can guess, but it's better if you make that explicit.

Comment: Don't change the title to include "solved." That's not how Stack Overflow works. Instead, mark the *answer* that solved your problem. If no answer solved it, then post your own answer and then mark it.

Comment: @Mohammad Why are you using Tnt Unicode components but then converting to ANSI? That seems pointless.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if you space in the file path expect, you can not pass a param like `''+myparam+''`

```
var
myparam : AnsiString;
begin
myparam := 'test file nr 10.txt';
ShellExecute(0, nil, PChar('...'), PChar(''+myparam+''), nil, SW_HIDE);
```

ParamStr(1) will give you only `test` !!

If you have spaces in the path use it like:

```
ShellExecute(0, nil, PChar('...'), PChar('"'+myparam+'"'), nil, SW_HIDE);
```

Try following. **but take care with the cast from `FFileName: WideString` to AnsiString, information may be lost. Use this only if there are no special characters in the file path occur.**

```
...
var
AnsiStr : AnsiString;
...
begin

AnsiStr := TntOpenDialog1.FileName;
ShellExecute(0, nil, PChar('E:\generic\mpv\mpv.exe'), PChar('"'+AnsiStr+'"'), nil, SW_HIDE);
```

Comment: Really? You think that asker has chosen to use Tnt Unicode components so that the Unicode strings can be converted to ANSI?

Comment: `You think that asker has chosen to use Tnt Unicode components` I don't know why asker has chosen. Also I don't know why asker has choosen `ShellExecute()` . **But I know that.** `if you are using parts of my answer should at least refer to my answer.` **My answer points first to the reason why his code in spite of your answer does not work.**

Comment: *it just shows me the first letter of file which I selected before* is pretty clearly down to encoding. And the code makes it clear that the encoding is wrong. Not quoting the arg is a useful catch. As for why asker is still stuck, well, asker didn't follow my advice. Anyway, I find it very odd that you recommend that the asker switches from Unicode to ANSI.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : I not `recommend that the asker switches from Unicode to ANSI` .I even warned him that parts can be removed if he uses it. **it is his decision to use Delphi7 or ShellExecute()**.

Comment: You do seem to recommend just that. Instead of using the Unicode API, all your code calls the ANSI API. The Unicode API can be reached readily from Delphi 7. That's why the asker has chosen Tnt Unicode components. All the asker needs to do is stick to the W suffixed APIs, and `WideString`. I suspect you might not be aware that Unicode is perfectly viable in Delphi 7.

Comment: `..... but it still can't make my program runs correctly –  @Mohammad Ari` (comment to your answer) . With your answer and the part of my answer `PChar('"'+aparam+'"')`, he will bring it finally up and running. So we're **both** happy to help him.

Comment: He didn't do what I said though. He called `ShellExecuteExW` passing a bogus argument. The Unicode encoding mismatch cannot be disputed. Your answer ignores that which is an omission. The parameter quoting is a good point. I missed that. Thank you.

Comment: I'm truly nubie for programming so I'm not sure that I understand with the discussion you both talking. But I use Tnt component because I use special character in my folder and need it to show correctly. @moskito-x I've tried your code and I've got it work except when I try to play 2 movies only 1 movie can play.  If anyone can help this please provide me the right answer

Comment: @MohammadArif : glad it works . for `I try to play 2 movies` that we need more code we can not see. You should also as mentioned by @DavidHeffernan use `ShellExecuteExW()`. If you have got it to run with `ShellExecuteExW()`, create a new question with code and the 2 movies problem. Your question is about `PChar(''+TntOpenDialog1.FileName+'')` and solved now.

Comment: Thanks a lot for direction

Answer (score 2):

You've got an encoding mismatch:

- `TntOpenDialog1.FileName` is UTF-16 encoded.
- `PChar` is an alias for `PAnsiChar` and so is ANSI.
- `ShellExecute` is an alias for `ShellExecuteA`, the ANSI variant.

This means that you are passing UTF-16 data to a function that expects ANSI encoded text. Hence the observed behaviour.

Replace `PChar` with `PWideChar` and `ShellExecute` with `ShellExecuteW` to correct that mismatch.

In the first instance, to convince yourself that this is the problem, change your debugging code to this:

```
TntLabel1.Caption := PWideChar(TntOpenDialog1.FileName);
```

Use `ShellExecuteExW` if you wish to be able to report errors properly. Use `CreateProcessW` to create the process directly and avoid involving the shell.

If

```
'' + TntOpenDialog1.FileName + ''
```

is not a typo from when you wrote the question, then that's a problem too. Because `''` is just the empty string.

In other words, that expression is equal to

```
TntOpenDialog1.FileName
```

You would need to use:

```
'"' + TntOpenDialog1.FileName + '"'
```

in order to quote the argument and escape any space characters.

Comment: Thankyou for quick answer. I'll try it and give report soon

Comment: I'm not sure I have done with this question. I have try several way like this:    ShellExecuteExW(PWideChar('e:\generic\mpv\mpv.exe '+TntOpenDialog1.FileName+''));
 but it still can't make my program runs correctly

Comment: That won't compile will it. You'll want to read the documentation for `ShellExecuteExW` carefully. Before hand, prove to yourself that the issue is as I describe by using ShellExecuteW`.

Comment: @moskito No. What I state is correct. `'' + S + '' = S`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : If variable `S` has a value like `S := 'S'` only then that's right.

Comment: @moskito-x No. You don't understand me at all. `'foo' + '' = 'foo'`. If you want to disagree with me, then please tell me what `'foo' + ''` is equal to if it is not equal to `'foo'`.  Anyway, you won this one. The asker doesn't care about Unicode. The asker did exactly what I said he would, and take your answer as a recommendation to use `AnsiString` rather than `WideString`. I was trying to help the asker avoid that pitfall, and be able to use Unicode. I think you've let the asker down here. That said, the asker didn't seem at all keen to learn.

Comment: @moskito-x So what I was doing was explaining that the asker thought he was concatenating quotes but was actually concatenating empty strings.

Comment: your statement is misleading : `In other words, that expression is equal to TntOpenDialog1.FileName` : a beginner will interpret this as : a  expression is past to mpv.exe as `E:\generic\mpv\mpv.exe TntOpenDialog1.FileName`. The questioner is simply overwhelmed with `ShellExecuteExW()`. Therefor it is useless to help with expert knowledge. Step by Step is rather my approach. What prevented you to help with a simple line as follows. : `ShellExecuteW(0, nil, 'E:\Generic\MPV\mpv.exe', PWideChar('"'+TntOpenDialog1.FileName+'"'), nil, SW_HIDE);` ::: Any confusion would be eliminated with one line.

Comment: @moskito I suppose I was trying to teach. The asker didn't want to learn and followed your bad advice to use ANSI. I don't see the point in writing the code and then have the asker just copy it without understanding. I try to pass on knowledge.

Comment: @moskito I think it would be best if you deleted the comments that you made that you now see contain false statements. To avoid further confusion.

Comment: `I suppose I was trying to teach` : and has brought nothing. My approach was to make first to run the simple code. To see if it works with OP's code, if this simple code would not have worked, then the error would be anywhere else. Step by step limit the error. But if the simple code works then I would have pointed out the use of `ShellExecuteW()`.